# How to filter tags in a component dialog. Adobe CQ

Tags: aem, xtype

I am trying to filter the tags in a component dialog. I know that I can filter it by namespace, however that applies only to root level. Can I filter the tag selection one level deeper?

for example:

- etc

  - tags

    - namespace

      - article-type

        - blog
        - news
      - asset-type

        - image
        - video

I want to filter the tags in the component dialog so the user can only select the tags under 'article-type'.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. Officially you can go deeper according to the widget API, but there is a "bug" in the Widget JavaScript file that prevents it to work. I had the same issue and I just overwrite this JavaScript file.

**Widget definition:**

```
<article jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="Article Type"
    name="./cq:tags"
    tagsBasePath="/etc/tags/namespace"
    xtype="tags">
    <namespaces jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <ns1 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" maximum="1" name="article-type" />  
    </namespaces>  
</article>
<asset jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="Asset Type"
    name="./cq:tags"
    namespaces="[asset-type]"
    tagsBasePath="/etc/tags/offering"
    xtype="tags"/>
```

In this case only one Tag below `article-type` can be selected; you can limit the number with the `maximum` attribute. The `asset-type` has no limits. So choose the option that suits your need.

**JavaScript overwrite:**

To make this work, you need to change the method `CQ.tagging.parseTag` in `/libs/cq/tagging/widgets/source/CQ.tagging.js`:

```
// private - splits tagID into namespace and local (also works for title paths)
CQ.tagging.parseTag = function(tag, isPath) {
    var tagInfo = {
        namespace: null,
        local: tag,
        getTagID: function() {
            return this.namespace + ":" + this.local;
        }
    };

    var tagParts = tag.split(':');
    if (tagParts[0] == 'article-type' || tagParts[0] == 'asset-type') {
        var realTag = tagParts[1];
        var pos = realTag.indexOf('/');
        tagInfo.namespace = realTag.substring(0, pos).trim();
        tagInfo.local = realTag.substring(pos + 1).trim();
    }
    else {
        // parse tag pattern: namespace:local
        var colonPos = tag.indexOf(isPath ? '/' : ':');
        if (colonPos > 0) {
            // the first colon ":" delimits a namespace
            // don't forget to trim the strings (in case of title paths)
            tagInfo.namespace = tag.substring(0, colonPos).trim();
            tagInfo.local = tag.substring(colonPos + 1).trim();
        }
    }
    return tagInfo;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas! Did you modify the CQ.tagging.js file in the libs folder itself? Or did you create an overlay for it?

Comment: @mayurM I actually overwrite the original file itself. Not sure if an overlay would work in this case as this is a JavaScript which is loaded through the clientlibrarymanager. But you could try if an overlay would work as well

Comment: Not sure can I ask this question or not, I am also working on the same tags dialog in CQ5. Can any one suggest me how to change the properties of width and height of that dialog. I tried in tags.jsp and tag field tab but no use.